# Arduino Nano 33 BLE GPS

Tags: c, arduino, gps

I want test my new GPS Board (NEO-M9N) with a simple example:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
static const int RXPin = 4, TXPin = 3;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;
// The serial connection to the GPS device
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    ss.begin(GPSBaud);
}
void loop()
{
// Output raw GPS data to the serial monitor
    while (ss.available() > 0){
        Serial.write(ss.read());
    }
}
```

However when I try to run it on my arduino nano 33 ble I got this error:

```
SoftwareSerial.h: No such file or directory
```

What do I need to do to run this code with arduino nano 33 ble?

Comment: Did you install the library in the library manager?

Comment: What is the full path to `SoftwareSerial.h`? (e.g.) If it's `/foo/bar/baz/include/SoftwareSerial.h`, you'd need to add `-I/foo/bar/baz/include` to the compiler command line. But, it may _not_ be installed. Usually, there is a config script for a given package that can tell you where `.h` and `.so` files are installed (e.g. `pkg-config`). BTW, based on `SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);` and `ss.begin(GPSBaud)`, this is _not_ valid `c` code. Looks a bit more like `c++`.

Comment: I tried this code with my Arduino Uno and it worked. Only my Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense has problems with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this forum topic](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=634959.0) it seems that `SoftwareSerial.h` does not exist for Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense boards. But following [this Github issue](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-nRF528x-mbedos/issues/38) serial communication can be created instead with:

```
UART mySerial(digitalPinToPinName(4), digitalPinToPinName(3), NC, NC);
```

Take a look at [this Github issue](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-nRF528x-mbedos/issues/45) as well.